# How to center the content of a web page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

At the zoom level showed in the screenshot below, the Wired site displays normally:

[image]

But as I zoomed out I could see that everything is at the center. When I made a web page similar to the web site in the image and zoomed out, mine did not look like the image below.

This web page is still centered but mine was left-aligned:

[image]

I want to know how to make my web page stay centered when zoomed out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
   width: 1350px;
   background-image: url("Images/background.png");
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   background-size: 1366;
  }
  .flex-container {
   display: flex;
   background-color: #3B5998;
   margin-left: -10px;
   margin-top: -20px;
   margin-right: -8px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #133783;
  }
  .flex-container > div {
   background-color: #3B5998;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size: 13px;   
  }
  input {
   border: 1px solid #1D2A5B;
   padding-bottom: 3px;
   padding-top: 3px;
  }
  a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #9CB4D8;
  }
  a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .column {
   float: left;
   width: 450px;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 300px;
  }
  .big-input {
   padding-bottom: 12px;
   padding-top: 12px;
   margin-top: 10px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="flex-container">
  <div style="margin-left: 169px; margin-top: 10px;">
   <img id="logo" style="margin-top: 16px;" src="Images/Facebook-img1.png" alt="LOGO" />
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; margin-left: 30%; font-family: helvetica; color: white;">
   <td>
   <form action="redirect.html">
    <table style="margin-top: 15px;">
     <tr>
      <td>Email or Phone</td>
      <td style="display: flex; margin-left: 10px;">Password</td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td style="display: flex; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;"><input type="password" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Log In" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td style="display: flex; margin-left: 10px;"><a href="recover.html" id="forgot">Forgotten Account?</a></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </form> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="middle">
 <div style="margin-left: 169px; margin-top: 5px;">
  <div class="column" style="margin-right: 115px;">
   <h2>Facebook helps you connect and share with the people in your life.</h2>
   <img src="Images/Facebook-img2.png" alt="We are Connected" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <form action="redirect.html">
   <h1>Creat an Account</h1>
   <p>It's free and always will be.</p>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td style="display: flex; padding-right: 12px;"><input style="width: 170px;" type="text" class="big-input"/></td>
     <td><input style="width: 170px;"type="text" class="big-input"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><input style="width: 358px;" class="dual big-input" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><input style="width: 358px;" class="dual big-input" type="text" /><td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <p>Birthday</p>
   <label for="day">Date</label>
   <input type="number" id="day" />
   <label for="month">Month</label>
   <input type="number" id="month" />
   <label for="year">Year</label>
   <input type="number" id="year" />
   <span>Why do I need to provide my Date of birth?</span>
   
   <input type="radio" id="male" />
   <label for="female">Female</label>
   <input type="radio" id="male" />
   <label for="male">Male</label>
   
   <p>By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our <a href="https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms/update">Terms,</a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/update">Data Policy</a> and <a href="https://www.facebook.com/policies/cookies/"> Cookie Policy.</a> You may receive SMS notifications from us and can opt out at any time.</p>
   
   <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
   
   <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/creation/?ref_type=registration_form">Create a Page</a> for a celebrity, band or business.</p>
   </form>
   
  </div>
  
 </div>  
 </div> 
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <img style="display: flex; width: 1300px;" src="Images/last.png" alt="Last pic" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe, I could Use the code. THEN You could see that in Zoom mode. I used 25% at         1366px X 768px       Resulation

Comment: Or, MAYBE NEED to use a Full different Code....   I was just looking for any trick that could immediately fix the error. Maybe that is not possible. I have got to use CSS "ALIGN: CENTER;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

This will make your website center aligned, i think that is what you want to do.

Comment: This won't always center.

Answer (score 0):

They aligned that part to center.

```
<h1 align="center">Some text.......</h1>
```

This is center aligned so even if you zoom out, it will stay in the center.
I think you should have added spaces for aligning in the center in your website.

Answer (score 0):

Their shell container most likely has a margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; attribute with a max-width added.

This is what I have on my site to make it behave this way.